# Create many non-child records in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form where I need users to be able to create many records, except the difference from the standard [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gem is that I'm not creating child records. Take, for example, a survey:

The questioner creates a `Survey`, which has many nested `SurveyQuestions`, each with some `SurveyOptions`. The answerer then goes to `SurveyAnswer.new` to answer some of these questions.

I need to be able to create multiple `SurveyAnswers` in one go. As this is creating multiple 'parents' rather than multiple 'children', it seems like a non-typical problem. How can I get this to work?

---

#### Update - questions don't only belong to surveys

The description I wrote above may be misleading - consider just `Questions`, to which users can create `Answers`. Some questions are bundled in surveys but many questions are free floating. This is why I thought it didn't make sense to bundle answers under anything except the user who created them.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Since scoping is not an option - here a solution that should work:

Controller:

```
  def new
    @questions = []
    (1..10).each do
      @questions << Question.new
    end
  end
  def create
    logger.info params[:questions].inspect
  end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for(:questions, :url => questions_path) do |f| %>
  <% prefix ||= 0 %>
  <% @questions.each do |n| %>
    <% prefix += 1 %>
    <%= f.fields_for(prefix.to_s ) do |child| %>
      <%= child.text_field :text %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= submit_tag :test %>
<% end %>
```

This will create a form with multiple children that looks similar to this:

```
<input id="questions_1_text" name="questions[1][text]" size="30" type="text" />    
<input id="questions_2_text" name="questions[2][text]" size="30" type="text" />
```

The parameters hash then looks like this:

> "questions"=>{"1"=>{"text"=>"foo"}, "2"=>{"text"=>"bar"},
>   "3"=>{"text"=>"anything"}, "4"=>{"text"=>"goes"}, "5"=>{"text"=>"here"},
>   "6"=>{"text"=>""}, "7"=>{"text"=>""}, "8"=>{"text"=>""},
>   "9"=>{"text"=>""}, "10"=>{"text"=>""}}, "commit"=>"test"}

As you can see you can simply access this hash in your controller through params[:questions]. 
You can loop through them and check wether or not they are empty and persist them to ActiveRecord.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have clarified my question. Thank you for your answer so far.